# Как оформить шаблон для однообразного использования как чисел, так и указателей?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64

Попытка раз:

```
  template<typename THigh, typename TLow>
    inline size_t compact(THigh hi, TLow lo){
        return (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(hi)<<32) | reinterpret_cast<size_t>(lo);
    }
```

Типы `THigh`, `TLow` могут быть числовым типом, либо указательным типом в любых сочетаниях. На предложенный вариант компилятор ругается `invalid cast`.

Попытка два:

```
  template<typename THigh, typename TLow>
    inline size_t compact(THigh hi, TLow lo){
        return (static_cast<size_t>(hi)<<32) | static_cast<size_t>(lo);
    }
```

Компилятор опять ругается `invalid static_cast`. Переделка в макрос даёт ровно ничего.
Можно написать четыре функции, но их код по сути идентичен.

Можно использовать устаревший с-стиль:

```
template<typename THigh, typename TLow>
    inline size_t compact(THigh hi, TLow lo){
        return ((size_t)(hi)<<32) | (size_t)(lo);
    }
```

Но этот стиль скрывает (малозаметный) приведение типов.

В целом нужно объединить все варианты:

`void*, size_t`

`size_t, void*`

`void*, void*`

Данная возможность нужна для преобразования данных из MMIO с доступом по 32 бита в указатели 64-битной системы. То есть старшая или младшая части являются числом, а остальное - указатель. Число и число будет лишь побочным эффектом.

`size_t` имеет разрядность 64 бита. Указатели - 64 бита. Всё - 64 бита, только одни параметры - числа, а другие указатели.

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать шаблонную функцию ptrToInt для преобразования указателя к size_t. reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr) - такое приведение вполне законно. А вашу функцию сделать нешаблонной, но придется использовать ptrToInt, когда передаете указатель в вашу функцию compact (ptrToInt(p), int)

Comment: @awesome идею не понял. Первый элемент тоже может быть числом.

Comment: а скажите откуда такой кейс, что указатель надо складывать с числом? и будет ли тот же самый смысл в сдвиге <<32 на 64-битной платформе?

Comment: А с каких это пор C-style касты являются deprecated? На чем основаны такие далеко идущие заявления?

Comment: @AnT вот из-за такого отношения современное ПО медленное, глючное и с врождёнными багами. Комментарий относится к вопросу ровно столько сколько нисколько, в нём отсутствует объективность по теме. Отсутствуют варианты решения или уточнения по теме.

Comment: @Adokenai Во-первых, нет, комментарий настолько "по теме", насколько это вообще возможно. Во-вторых, сама "тема" еще толком не ясна, ибо в вопросе вы не удосужились даже объяснить, что же именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Потрудитесь в будущем начинать именно с такого объяснения, а не с каких-то непонятно откуда и зачем взявшихся "попыток раз". Это что касается "отношения"...

Comment: @AnT обновление без кэша Ctrl+F5

Comment: @Adokenai https://pastebin.com/RAefak3W

Comment: `#define HighLo(h, l) ((((uint64_t)(h)) << 32 ) | (uint64_t)(l))` чем не годится?

Comment: @avp это третий из вариантов

Comment: @awesome идея понятна, но в таком случае можно обойтись без шаблонов. Похоже иного решения нет. Пишите в ответ, подтвержу.

Comment: @Adokenai, если я правильно понял задачу, то в 32-bit системе вы тоже должны получать 64-bit результат. Если это так, то ни ваш 3-й из вариантов, ни принятый ответ не годятся, поскольку возвращаемый тип `size_t` в такой системе имеет размер 32 бита.

Comment: *"из-за такого отношения современное ПО медленное, глючное и с врождёнными багами"* Мне кажется, имеется в виду, что стандарт четко определяет, что является deprecated, а что нет. Как минимум формально С-касты не deprecated. *"глючное и с врождёнными багами"* Ну не знаю. Использовать С-касты с указателями и ссылками действительно рискованно, а вот кастовать в числовые типы - по-моему вполне безопасно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну, не то слово выбрал. В конечном итоге, такие длинные наименовать *_cast созданы специально. Хотя я не понимаю сути создания отдельных *_cast для чисел и указателей. Если уж использовал *_cast, то сделал это сознательно. В любом случае комментарий AnT помог в решении вопроса ровно нисколько. Все остальные хоть что-то предложили. Для меня AnT теперь просто спаммер. За сим оффтоп прошу закончить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A
{

};

size_t ptrToInt(void* p)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(p);
}

size_t compact(size_t h, size_t l)
{
    return (h << 32) | l;
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    int b = 5;

    size_t res = compact(ptrToInt(a), b);
    size_t res2 = compact(b, ptrToInt(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В 32-bit системе старшая часть просто отрезается

Comment: Почему вдруг для представления указателя используется `size_t`?

Comment: @AnT потому что в size_t можно безопасно помещать указатель.

Comment: В `size_t` *нельзя* безопасно помещать указатель. Безопасно помещать указатель можно в `uintptr_t`, а не в `size_t`.

Comment: size_t это синоним для uintptr_t и UINT_PTR. Можно ссылку на стандарт, где говорится, что size_t необязательно совпадает с размером указателя?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t/

It is a type able to represent the size of any object in bytes: size_t is the type returned by the sizeof operator and is widely used in the standard library to represent sizes and counts.

Comment: @awesome На практике я ни разу не видел, чтобы эти типы отличались, но формально, как мне кажется, AnT прав. Если открыть [`[implimits]/2.17`](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.17), то там написано, что реализация вправе ввести произвольное ограничение на размер объектов. Если сделать ограничение достаточно маленьким, то может получиться так, что будет достаточно size_t меньшего по размеру, чем указатели.

Comment: *"Можно ссылку на стандарт, где говорится, что size_t необязательно совпадает с размером указателя"* Странно просить ссылку на отрицательное утверждение. Найдите мне ссылку на стандарт, где написано, что вы не верблюд. :р

Comment: `size_t` определяется как `long unsigned int` (см. включаемые файлы). А вот `long` - разной размерности. В вопросе идёт речь о `long` размером 64 бита (LP64). `size_t` модели `LLP64` является 32-битным и явно недостаточным для содержания указателя. https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: @Adokenai Если у вас в хедерах стоит `long unsigned int`, это не значит, что это единственное допустимое определение. На моем mingw gcc (64-битном) в хедере вообще написано `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;`, и методом тыка обнаружилось, что `__SIZE_TYPE__` означает `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я рассматривал STL-библиотеку под Linux и там `size_t` определён как `long unsigned int`. Именно так. Иначе самопальный `initializer_list` просто не компилировался.

Comment: @Adokenai На разных платформах определения могут быть разные. В стандарте не написано, что должен быть `unsigned long`. Любая реализация может выбрать любой подходящий тип. Это вам просто везет. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat согласен, в этом плане стандарт хромает. Чуть позже `long long` станет 128-битным и всё опять "поплывёт". Для ясности добавил ещё параграф в дополнение к вопросу, у которого уже выбран ответ.

Comment: @awesome: Это вы нам должны привести ссылку на стандарт с такими странными заявлениями как "size_t это синоним для uintptr_t". Что это за чушь??? Тип `size_t` не имеет никакого даже отдаленного отношения к указателям и в общем случае имеет размер на порядки меньший, чем размер указателя (возьмите любую платформу с сегментной памятью). Использовать `size_t` для представления указателей - грубейшая ошибка. Для этих целей предназначен именно специально заведенный тип `uintptr_t`.